# onclick event not updating state on first click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

tryng to create fields with validation if field isEmpty deprecate onClick action but in first click mine deprecation not working only after second click it's working and updating state how i want im using react redux state managment canot see couse of mine mistake in code its mine component

```
    const state = useSelector(state => state.fieldsReducer.fields);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const AddTransaction =  () => {
         dispatch(fieldsValidation(state.title.value, state.amount.value));
        if (state.title.isCorrectValue || state.amount.isCorrectValue) {
            return false;
        }
        dispatch(addExpense(state.title.value, state.amount.value))
    };

    return (
        <div className='add-transaction-wrapper'>
            <div className='add-expense-inputs-wrapper'>
                <TextField
                    id='title'
                    label='title'
                    value={state.title.value}
                    onChange={e => dispatch(onHandleChange(e, e.target.id))}
                    error={state.title.isCorrectValue}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="amount"
                    label="expense amount"
                    type="number"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                    value={state.amount.value}
                    onChange={e => dispatch(onHandleChange(e, e.target.id))}
                    error={state.amount.isCorrectValue}
                />
                <button
                    onClick={() => AddTransaction()}
                    className='submit-button'
                >
                    Add transaction
                     </button>
            </div>
            <TransactionDash />
        </div>
    )
```

here is mine reducer

```
case VALIDATEFIELDS:
            // Object.assign(state.fields)
            return {
                ...state,
                fields: {
                    ...state.fields,
                    title: {
                        ...state.fields.title,
                        isCorrectValue: checkValue(action.payload.title) ? true : false
                    },
                    amount: {
                        ...state.fields.amount,
                        isCorrectValue: checkValue(action.payload.amount) ? true : false
                    }
                }
            }
```

her is mine action creator

```
export const fieldsValidation = (titleValue, amountValue) => (
    {
        type: types.VALIDATEFIELDS,
        payload: {
            title: titleValue,
            amount: amountValue
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Dispatching is not synchronous. You can't get the new value of `x.isCorrectValue` immediately after dispatching your action. Call `checkValue` inside the `AddTransaction` operation to get the required information up front.

Comment: console.log show me for first time result of dispatching fieldsValidation returned same state and only after second call it's correct i dk wat to search or use im tried to use async await at mine addTransaction functin but without sucess result

Comment: @vakhozhgenti state in AddTransaction is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). You can make `fieldsValidation` a thunk and return a boolean or run an effect when the isCorrectValue change.